# Error al cargar archivo con php

Tags: php, mysql

al tratar de subir un archivo, me da siempre el mismo mensaje de error, que es "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño". El archivo que intento subir es un pdf, que está dentro de los permitidos y su tamaño es de 19KB. Os pongo el código, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Lo que intento es poder subir un archivo para que se quede guardado en la base de datos y así poder recuperarle cuando sea necesario. El usuario tiene que poder subir los tipos de archivo que veis en el código y yo creo que el problema no es ni el tamaño ni el tipo de archivo.
Gracias de antemano a todos.

```
<?php

    require 'funcs/funcs.php';
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$estado_civil = $_POST['estado_civil'];

$sql = "UPDATE empleados SET nombre='$nombre', correo='$email', telefono='$telefono', estado_civil='$estado_civil' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$id_insert = $id;

if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){
    echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
    } else {

    $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","application/pdf", "application/msword");
    $limite_kb = 8000;

    if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

        $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
        $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];

        if(!file_exists($ruta)){
            mkdir($ruta);
        }

        if(!file_exists($archivo)){

            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

            if($resultado){
                echo "Archivo Guardado";
                } else {
                echo "Error al guardar archivo";
            }

            } else {
            echo "Archivo ya existe";
        }

        } else {
        echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
    }

}
```

Comment: Creo recordar que `$_FILES["archivo"]["size"]` devolvía el valor en bytes por lo que en tu tamaño maximo que estas usando es 8000 bytes. Un archivo de 19 KB esta por encima de ese máximo.

Answer (score 2):

en primer lugar quiero proponerte organizar un poquito mejor el código para facilitar su lectura:

```
<?php

require 'funcs/funcs.php';
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$estado_civil = $_POST['estado_civil'];

$sql = "UPDATE empleados SET nombre='$nombre', correo='$email', telefono='$telefono', estado_civil='$estado_civil' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$id_insert = $id;


if ($_FILES["archivo"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error al cargar archivo";
    return;
}

$permitidos = array(
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
    "application/pdf",
    "application/msword"
);

$limite_kb = 8000;

$is_file_in_array = in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos);
$max_file_size = $limite_kb * 1024;
$is_allowed_size = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $max_file_size;

$allow_file_status = $is_file_in_array && $is_allowed_size;
if(!$allow_file_status){
    echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
    return;
}

$ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
$archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];

if(!file_exists($ruta)){
    mkdir($ruta);
    echo "Nueva carpeta creada";
}

if(file_exists($archivo)){
    echo "El archivo ya existe";
    return;

}

$save_file_status = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

if(!$save_file_status){
    echo "Error al guardar archivo";
    return;
}

echo "Archivo Guardado";
```

1º Cambiaría el orden de ejecución. Primero realizar comprobaciones que puedan detener el flujo y evitar almacenar información o realizar procesos innecesarios, es decir, que no se vayan a usar porque el flujo se detuvo antes.
Por otra parte, como puedes observar, evitar anidar demasiados ifs y else, realizando algo llamado "Salva guarda"

Sinceramente, te recomiendo muchísimo leer a este autor, Martin Fowler (es todo un referente).
En su web puedes ver numerosos ejemplos relacionados con la arquitectura de software, patrones de diseño y como crear código mucho mas limpio y ordenado. Te invito a cultivarte en las buenas prácticas del desarrollo de software. (muy valorado en el mundo del desarrollo de software hoy en día ya que permite reducir el coste asociado al mantenimiento del mismo)

Creo que si estás iniciado recientemente o desde hace poco en la programación, no hay nada mejor que tener alguien de referencia. Martin Fowler, Kent Beck o Robert C. Martin 
https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Ahora, volviendo a tu pregunta, 
¿Podrías confirmar que realmente obtienes 'TRUE' justo en este punto?

```
$allow_file_status = $is_file_in_array && $is_allowed_weight;
```

Está claro que no, pero...también desconozco los datos que regresas exactamente, que archivo de ejemplo intentas introducir, por ello busco ayudarte basándome en la lógica

Te invito a desglosar el código y ver que retorna justo en el punto:

Divide y vencerás! :D

de

```
$allow_file_status = in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024;
```

a

```
$is_file_in_array = in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos);
$max_file_size = $limite_kb * 1024;
$is_allowed_size = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $max_file_size;

$allow_file_status = $is_file_in_array && $is_allowed_size;
```

Por una parte creo que es algo mas legible y estructurado. Por otra parte, ahora puedes realizar un var_dump(),de esas 3 variables POR SEPARADO y ver:

Comprobar el tipo de dato que regresa

Creo que haciendo esto darás con la solución, ya que vas a ver de manera intrínseca, porque tienes false u otra cosa(error) en la expresión que quieres que sea true. Son operaciones localizadas, 1 cálculo y 2 condiciones.
Que exista el archivo
Que el cálculo de tamaño de archivo sea el esperado y CONCUERDE con la MEDIDA a interpretar por el servidor. (es como si tu le envias 'Tengo 10'en kb y tu servidor interpreta 'Okey 10' gb), pues excede.

Y finalmente que en la comparación de tamaño el numero de un lado sea mayor al otro.

Comment: Buenos días Sergio. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios y recomendaciones. Tienes razón en que estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación. Seguiré tus sugerencias y veré donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Buenos días Sergio. Ahora ya me sube el archivo, pero no quisiera que fuese obligatoria la carga. Me puedes ayudar? como hacer que no sea obligatoria? Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Monica, disculpa el no contestar pero bueno, la vida va dando vueltas y ahora ando bastante ocupado. Intentaré ayudarte en lo que pueda. ¿Como va el tema? Saludos